# Converting a multi column range into one column

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, named-ranges

I have an instance where I would love to be able to get a column of all the unique names in a range.  The problem I am having is that the range is multicolumn.

Let's assume my data is in A1:B3
This works fine if I do:

`=unique({A1:A3;B1:B3;C1:C3})`

But if that range is named and I do

`=unique(NamedRange)` or `=unique(A1:C3)`

Then it will spill over the column.  Worse if I want to filter or sort the results in the same formula and then run into errors because the formulas want single column/row or the rows/columns don't match anymore.

I don't deal with named ranges a lot, but I did just make a formula today that had 10 columns in it that I stuck into a range like that so that I could do a complex (for me) filter that gave me the difference of two different ranges, similar to: `=FILTER({B4:B93;C4:C93;D4:D93;E4:E93;F4:F93}, NOT(COUNTIF(H5:H, {B4:B93;C4:C93;D4:D93;E4:E93;F4:F93})))`.  I would REALLY love if I could clean that up and make that messy set B4:F instead.

Is there any formula level function that could stick these all in one column?
Usually I am looking to do other things with it like sort and filter and the multiple columns get even messier.

Thanks for your time.  I DID try searching for this, but I could not seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FLATTEN`:

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A1:C3))
```

or

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(NamedRange))
```

[image]

Comment: seems like in his specific case he'd want ...TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(A1:C3)) right?

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid that I just didn't know the name of.  THANKYOU.  Flatten is what I needed.